# Ubuntu - Getting audio to play from local speakers over SSH

Tags: audio, ssh, ubuntu-9.04, xorg, pulse-audio

In Intrepid, when I logged into my desktop over SSH and launched Rhythmbox (`ssh hostname -XYC`), it would play the sound out the desktop's speakers, which is what I want.  Now in Jaunty, it plays the sound out my laptop's speakers, which I don't want.  How do I configure the audio to come out the server's speakers when I connect to it over SSH?  Has this changed again in Karmic?

Do you know of a better solution for this problem?  (Sending audio from laptop to server wastes bandwidth compared to just sending the GUI data from server to laptop.)

Comment: I had "Enable network access to local sound devices" enabled on the laptop, and when I disable this, the sound on my laptop stops.  It doesn't play through on the desktop, though.

Comment: If I run music players in an NX windows, the audio goes to the right place.  Kind of a kludge, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled "Enable network access to local sound devices" and "Make discoverable network sound devices available locally", then rebooted.  Now the sound comes out the local speaker instead.  I have no idea why it connects backwards like that when logged in over SSH.

Answer (score -1):

```
ssh -X user@server "audio-player-application"
```

This plays music on the server, but displays GUI on the client ;) "-X" stands for "X session forwarding". Also try "-C" to compress the data, and "-fnN": this makes `ssh` go background after it asks for password.

Comment: That's what I'm using.  It plays the music on the laptop.